# Dynamic Optimization : Resource Stock as a Sink

Tags: environmental-economics, economic-growth, dynamic-optimization

I think about a dynamic problem where social planner maximizes the following utility ;

$$\underset{c\left(t\right)}{max}\int_{0}^{\infty}u\left(c\left(t\right)\right)e^{-\rho t}$$

subject to two constraints

$$\dot{K}\left(t\right)=AK\left(t\right)-c\left(t\right)$$

$$\dot{S}\left(t\right)=\left(1-S\left(t\right)\right)S\left(t\right)-\gamma AK\left(t\right)$$

where $S(t)$ and $K(t)$ hold for natural capital (seas, lakes, forests etc.) and physical capital respectively. $c(t)$ represents consumption.

In this $AK$ model, physical capital generates some wastes which are harmful to natural resource stock with a constant parameter $\gamma$. 
This feature is close to [Wirl (2004)](https://ideas.repec.org/a/eee/dyncon/v28y2004i6p1149-1157.html) in environmental economics literature.

The Hamiltonian of the problem is

$$\mathcal{H}=u\left(c\left(t\right)\right)+\lambda\left(t\right)\left(AK\left(t\right)-c\left(t\right)\right)+\mu\left(t\right)\left(\left(1-S\left(t\right)\right)S\left(t\right)-\gamma AK\left(t\right)\right)$$

$\lambda$ and $\mu$ are co-state variables for physical and natural capital.

Dynamics of co-state variables are

$$\dot{\lambda}=\rho\lambda+\mu\gamma A-\lambda A$$

$$\dot{\mu}=\rho\mu-\mu\left(1-2S\right)$$

In fact, in this model, it is easy to remark that natural capital don't have any ***amenity value*** don't provide any positive utility and it is just like a "sink".

As the social planner just takes into account the negative effect of capital accumulation (it creates wastes), I think natural capital enters in this model as a "cost".

Then, is it possible to say that $\mu$ could take a negative value as natural capital represents a cost for capital accumulation ?

Comment: A reference or link to Wirl (1994) would be helpful - he had several papers  in 1994: see https://ideas.repec.org/e/pwi178.html.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong for reference indeed. Thanks for the remark. I put the link.

Comment: I think the model needs a bit more specification.  Presumably it's required that $S(t) \geq 0$?  If so, what happens if $S(t)$ approaches zero?  Is $AK(t)$ then constrained so as not to take $S(t)$ below zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"Then, is it possible to say that $\mu$ could take a negative value as natural capital represents a cost for capital accumulation ?"*

No. $\mu$ can be thought of as the shadow price of natural resources. Being a "price", it has to be non-negative.
Note that if we set $\mu=0$ the problem reverts back to the standard model, which has an intuitive explanation: if "we don't care" about natural resources, their "price" is zero.

To see this from another route, for the standard CRRA utility function

$$u(c) = \frac {c^{1-\theta}-1}{1-\theta}$$

we would get

$$\frac {\dot c}{c} = \frac{1}{\theta}[A-\rho] - \frac{1}{\theta}\frac{\mu}{\lambda}\gamma A$$

So if $\mu <0$ we would obtain a *higher* consumption growth rate, which doesn't sound very plausible if by  $\mu <0$ we would want to express that "we care" about natural resources and so we would *lower* capital accumulation that hurts them, and consequently *lower* the consumption growth rate.

Comment: Thanks Alecos, you are wright. Once I wrote the steady state equilibrium, I saw that a negative $\mu$ does not make sense.